# No build task to run found. Configure Build Task

Tags: json, build, salesforce, lwc

When I am trying to run my build task, I'm getting this message -

*No build task to run found. Configure Build Task...*

I have the following 'tasks.json' file stored inside '.vscode'

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "ELTOROIT PushWhenBuild",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "sfdx force:source:push --json --forceoverwrite",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "panel": "dedicated",
            "clear": true,
            "focus": false,
            "showReuseMessage": true
        }
    }]
}
```

I tried closing and reopening VS code several times as suggested in other threads but this is not solving my issue.